# How to import Package (not module)?

Tags: powershell

I installed the SharpDx package from [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/4.2.0) but is there a way to import it, just like import-module, so that I wouldnt have to specify the assembly (dll) path(s)?

For now, the only way I found is to use Add-Type to reference the assembly but is there no other way besides this?

```
#Reference where you kept the dxSharp files
$dxSharpPath = 'Path\To\DLLs'

#Load the sharpDX Libraries
Add-Type -Path "$dxSharpPath\sharpdx.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$dxSharpPath\Sharpdx.Directinput.dll"

#Create new DirectInput object
$dInput = New-Object -TypeName SharpDX.DirectInput.DirectInput
```

I am ultimately trying to create the directinput object

Comment: from what i can tell, the only way to do that is the method you have used. i _presume_ you could wrap it in a module and use that if you want to hide the details. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ya...I was hoping thered be a simple import module like way...

Comment: it looks like you would need to build it yourself. i cannot find any hints that anyone has done it already. good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must tell PowerShell where the DLL is, no different than you'd have to if you loaded a module (.psm1 file with or without a manifest) of which you did not install to one of the defined PowerShell module paths.

Instead of Add-Type, you can also use reflection:

```
$customDLL = 'UncToYourDLL'
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($customDll)
```

See also Lee Holmes article on the topic here:

[Load a Custom DLL from PowerShell](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell)

**Update**

```
Import-Module SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll
```

Import-Module : The specified module 'SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Of course, that error is pretty specific. It has no idea where to find it, because that name does not match a module name.

So, this ...

```
Import-Module 'c:\users\mj\desktop\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll'
```

Or create a folder of the same basename as the DLL in the PSModulePath, copy the DLL to the that named folder and use import as normal

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP\SomeNewCustomOr3rdP.dll'
```

Then this...

```
Import-Module SomeNewCustomOr3rdP
```

... should work as expected. All-in-all, Add-Type, Import-Module, and [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($customDll), all accomplish the same thing.

***Update regarding getting SharpDX as a module***

Note that this is Install-Module and InstallPackage cmdlets. Both to the same thing for the target resource. If it exists via either, then the approach is the same for getting/using them.

```
# Find all modules wiht share in the name
Find-Module -Name '*Sharp*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

Version        Name                             Repository Description                                                                                              
-------        ----                             ---------- -----------                                                                                              
0.9.1.326      ACMESharp                        PSGallery  Client library for the ACME protocol, which is used to interoperate with the Let's Encrypt project's C...
0.9.3.334      ACMESharp.Providers.IIS          PSGallery  Microsoft IIS Provider extension library for ACMESharp Client.                                           
0.9.1.326      ACMESharp.Providers.AWS          PSGallery  AWS Provider extension library for ACMESharp Client.                                                     
0.9.1.326      ACMESharp.Providers.Windows      PSGallery  Microsoft Windows Providers extension library for ACMESharp Client.                                      
0.0.1          SNMPSharpNet                     PSGallery  PowerShell module implementing SNMP cmdlets from the SNMP Sharp .NET Library                             
0.9.1.326      ACMESharp.Providers.CloudFlare   PSGallery  CloudFlare Provider extension library for ACMESharp Client.                                              
1.0.1          CowsaySharp                      PSGallery  Generates ASCII pictures of a cow with a message                                                         
1.0.4          ACMESharpRoute53Automation       PSGallery  ACMESharpRoute53Automation is a PowerShell module which automates the ACMESharp process of obtaining S...
0.9.1.326      ACMESharp.Providers.DNSMadeEasy  PSGallery  DNS Made Easy Provider extension library for ACMESharp Client.                                           
1.0.6563.38109 ACMESharp.Providers.QCloud       PSGallery  A QCloud dns provider for handling Challenges.                                                           
0.1.0          PSCSharpInvoker                  PSGallery  Adds a cmdlet that can be used to invoke C# code without loading the types in the current PowerShell n...
1.0.0.0        IntelliTect.ResharperNugetSearch PSGallery  Provides functions for searching against Jet Brains' Resharper Nuget Search API.                         
1.3.5          CSharp-Watch                     PSGallery  Watches the current directory and sub-directories for changes to C-Sharp files. When a change is detec...
#>

# find all packages with sharp in the name
Find-Package -Name '*Sharp*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Get the detail on SharpDx specifically
Find-Package -Name 'SharpDX'
<#
# Results

Name                           Version          Source           Summary                                                                                            
----                           -------          ------           -------                                                                                            
SharpDX                        4.2.0            nuget.org        Core assembly for all SharpDX assemblies.  
#>
Find-Package -Name 'SharpDX' | 
Format-List

# Download and save a module or package
Find-Package -Name 'SharpDX' | 
Save-Package -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
Install-Package -Name 'SharpDX' -Force
```

Comment: Oh I thought there must be another way to do this like import-module. Oh well, thanks !

Comment: No worries, you can import DLL, but you still have to tell it the path. Since DLLs are not modules, and thus cannot be auto-loaded from module paths. See my update for you relative to this comment.

Comment: Than you for expanding on my comment. If I may ask, sqlserver is a module that I can easily import using import-module. Do you know if SharpDx is also available as a module instead of a package? For example, if we want to build SSAS tabular cubes, we can load the partial assembly/dll such as loadwithpartialname(Microsoft.Analysisservices.tabular). But we can also use sqlserver module itself to accomplish all the capabilities of this assembly, thus we wouldnt need to load the tabular assembly at all. Could SharpDx have something like that?

Comment: All available modules and packages are on the MS powershellgallery.com. Find them using the Find-Module, Find-Package cmdlets. See my update for you.